# Html.ValidationMessage is not displaying the message

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I have a controller and in that I am adding the error(exception) to the `ModelState`. And in the View when I try to do display the message via `Html.ValidationMessage()` it is not displaying the message. Can anyone help me with this?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FooMeth()
{
   ....
   if(cond == false)
   {
     ModelState.AddModelError("mykey","mymessage");
   }
   ....
   return View("fooView",mymodel);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("foo")
@Html.ValidationMessage("mykey")
```

Instead of showing the "mymessage" it will be blank always.Can anybody tell me whats the reason behind this?

Comment: what are you returning from action? can you show that?

Comment: what are you returning, after adding `ModelState.AddError` .

Comment: set validation summary true
@html.validationmessagefor(model=>model.mykey)
it will work for you or better to store in tempdata or in viewbag because modelstate create error for every new request so it might be chances of data lost

Answer (score 1):

If the above answers didn't work in your case, try these

1)Look if unobtrusive js is loading 
2)Add new AjaxOptions { **InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "IdXXX"**} for Ajax.BeginForm and inside form show @Html.ValidationSummary or Message

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ViewModel in your View, and then you can use Razor Helper according to your ViewModel properties:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)
```

And add this to your View, so that it will displays the validation results

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Comment: What's wrong in using this this statement. `ModelState.AddModelError("mykey","mymessage");`  It will also show the error.

Comment: @AmitKumar One is in the action (to add the error) the other is in the view (to display it)

Answer (score -1):

I think the best option would be to use a model and data annotations.
Or display the error text using ViewBag. I also see that you are sending mymodel
to the view but it has not been declared.

ViewBag Method:

C#:

```
using MyProject.Models;

public ActionResult FooMeth(MyModel model)
{
    if (cond == false)
    {
        // If failed, return input data and display error.
        ViewBag.ServerReply = "My Message.";
        return View(model);
    }
    // If successful return to black page.
    return View();
}
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
@ViewBag.ServerReply
```

Or you could just use model validation with data annotations:

Model & Data Annotations Method:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in text box.")]
    [StringLength(62, ErrorMessage = "Text must be {0} characters or less.")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

C#

```
using MyProject.Models;

public ActionResult FooMeth(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Code here if successful.
    }
    // If model is not valid return model with error messages. 
    return View(model);
}
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)
```